# vim tagbar and audible bell on initial tagbar toggle

Tags: vim, tagbar

I've noticed that the terminal audible bell sounds when the vim *tagbar* plugin first toggles on when I open a file. Subsequently toggling *tagbar* off and on again doesn't cause the audible bell. So, every time I open a source file, I get a bell sound; it's annoying.

I've turned off the audible bell for now in my terminal, so now I just get a visual bell instead (the terminal flashes momentarily every time I open a source file). This is livable, but I'd still like to get to the bottom of why a bell is being produced when the *tagbar* displays in vim.

I've turned on `:TagbarDebug` mode and pored through the *tagbardebug.log*. Nothing jumps out at me from that log file. I've also run vim with the `-V` option and pored through that debug output. The alarm bell sounds when the tagbar is toggled on, but there're no errors that stand out to me in vim's verbose output.

I'm using:

- VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 30 2014 10:56:39)
- tagbar installed via [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)

:: **Update** :: 
I've learned that, when installed via Vundle, the problem with *tagbar* and the audible bell occurs. When I install *tagbar* manually into my `.vim` directory, the problem doesn't manifest.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with just Vim and the Tagbar plugin? Then, open an issue at Tagbar's issue tracker.

Comment: This did the trick, @IngoKarkat, thanks! I opened an issue and the maintainer of *tagbar* fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing *tagbar* manually in the `.vim` directory or via another plugin manager — such as [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) — resolves the issue: no audible bell when when toggling on *tagbar*.

Apparently, there's a bad interaction between *tagbar* and Vundle. I opened up [an issue](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/issues/355) in *tagbar*'s issue tracker and the *tagbar* maintainer [fixed the bug](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/commit/56bee63e17924852caf19eb28b7173e5b6b5b4e9) on October 28th, 2016.